# javascript recursion return wrong value

Tags: javascript, recursion

There is a piece of recursive function that I was working on and it seems to be returning the wrong value than what is expected. I was able to replicate it and simplify the function into:

```
function foo(i, target){    
    if(i < target){
        i++;
        foo(i, target);
    }

    return i;   
}
console.log(foo(0,5));
```

Basically, given the function above, I expect the return value to be 5. However, it seems to return 1. When I did some tracing, I notice that "return i" is being called several times and each time it gets decremented with 1? What's the reason for this behaviour and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need also to return form the `if` part in your code.

```js
function foo(i, target){    
    if(i < target){
        i++;
        return foo(i, target);
    }
   
    console.log(i);
    return i;   
}

console.log(foo(0,5));
```

**Why your code returns 1?**

Because it only calls the `foo` every time while `i < target` and after it you get all values returned from the nested calls in order `5, 4, 3, 2, 1` and the last one is returned from the first function call is printed. You can check this by putting simple `console.log` before the `return i` and compare to the above result.

```js
function foo(i, target){    
    if(i < target){
        i++;
        foo(i, target);
    }
   
    console.log(i);
    return i;   
}

console.log(foo(0,5));
```

To visualize the returned values you can see

```
 console.log()                               console.log()
 |   Call with 1                             -- return Call with 1
 |   |   Call with 2                            -- return Call with 2
 |   |   |   Call with 3                           -- return Call with 3
 |   |   |   |   Call with 4                          -- return Call with 4
 |   |   |   |   |   Call with 5        VS               -- return Call with 5  
 |   |   |   |   |   return 5
 |   |   |   |   return 4
 |   |   |   return 3
 |   |   return 2
 |-- return 1
```

Comment: Thanks you for you explanation on why it returned 1. It gave me an idea and ran the trace again. There I noticed the call stack with several foo calls and as I step over "return i" , each call gets popped.

Comment: See also the visualization I made, it can help you

Comment: How do you do the trace with Google Dev Tools?

Comment: @Soolie Press F12 and go to Sources tab

Comment: yup, there is a "Call Stack" section

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the value of the recursive call

```js
function foo(i, target){    
    if(i < target){
        i++;
        return foo(i, target);
    }

    return i;   
}
console.log(foo(0,5));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give `return` to the recursive function call as well:

```
return foo(i, target);
```

```js
function foo(i, target) {
  if (i < target) {
    i++;
    // Change here...
    return foo(i, target);
  }
  return i;
}
console.log(foo(0, 5));
```

Comment: apologies @Soolie but I have to give it to Suren Srapyan for helping me understand why it was returning 1. cheers!